# Exporting XML to .plain text file in Dynamics AX

Tags: xml, xslt, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, xslcompiledtransform

This is with regards to the posts in this thread.
http://microsoft.public.axapta.programming.narkive.com/32IFWvdU/dax-4-0-aif-only-xml-format-possible-for-outbound-file

I am trying to do the exactly same thing in AX 2012. The thing that I am not understanding in this post is where it says, "in the writefile method of your new adapter
you can do the xslt transform and you get the csv....". How can I do xslt transform in the code in AX 2012. I tried to use XSLCompiledTransform class but it just supports supports xml and is used to transform XML to XML only. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In DAX2012 inbound and outbound transformations can be setup in Processing options group of Inbound service that you use for exchange data. You can use XSL transformations or you can create you own .NET assembly transform as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg863930.aspx)